# Golang Gin retrieve integer data

Tags: go, frameworks, go-gin, strconv

I'm trying to retrieve int data from POST requisitions with Gin, but I'm getting an error saying that the functions (PostForm, or any other) expects strings as arguments. I've tried to search for a function expecting int content, but with no success.
I have a struct do define the content, see the code below.

```
package userInfo

import(
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age int
}

func ReturnPostContent(c *gin.Context){
    var user Person
    user.Name = c.PostForm("name")
    user.Age = c.PostForm("age")    
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{        
        "user_name": user.Name,
        "user_age": user.Age,       
    })
}
```

I was thinking in converting the value to int, but if I have 10 inputs this becomes very difficult and impractible.

The error from user.Age:

```
cannot use c.PostForm("age") (value of type string) as int value in assignmentcompiler
```

Comment: Use `strconv.Atoi` to convert a string to integer.

Comment: I know about that, but if I have too much inputs this may be a problem, I'd like to know if theres an easier way to get int data with Gin Gonic. I've tried to search for it, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Then you're probably looking for this: [Bind Query String or Post Data](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#readme-bind-query-string-or-post-data)

Comment: Tks dude, worked for me!!

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of source code reading, I finally found out that all you need is to add a 'form' tag on the required field:

```
Age int `form:"age"`
```

Answer (score 3):

user `strconv.Atoi(c.PostForm("age"))`

complete code:

Person:

```golang
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

```golang
r.POST("/profile", func(c *gin.Context) {
    profile := new(Person)

    profile.Name = c.PostForm("name")
    profile.Age, _ = strconv.Atoi(c.PostForm("age"))

    response := gin.H{
        "user_name": profile.Name,
        "user_age":  profile.Age,
    }
    
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, response)

})
```

[image: hit the API]